# SimpleJdbcCall can not call more than one procedure

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

`SimpleJdbcCall` can not call more than one procedure

this is my test code :

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;


public class TestCall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "spring/applicationContext.xml",
                        "spring/applicationDb.xml" });

        SimpleJdbcCall call = context.getBean("simpleJdbcCall",
                SimpleJdbcCall.class);

        call.withProcedureName("proc1").execute("p1", "p2");

        System.out.println("CallString: " + call.getCallString());

        call.withProcedureName("proc2").execute("p1");

        System.out.println("CallString: " + call.getCallString());

    }
}
```

in the code , I defined `simpleJdbcCall`

```
<bean id="simpleJdbcCall" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall" >
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

and procedure `proc1` receives 2 paramaters , adn procedure `proc2` receives 1 paramater.

When I run it, exception occured.

Then I debug and found out that `AbstractJdbcCall.callString` is still 
CallString: `{call proc1(?, ?)}`
when call `proc2`.

So, is it a Spring's bug ?

And Is there anyone to tell me how to contact the author Thomas Risberg ?

Answer (score 21):

> So, is it a Spring's bug ?

No, you're just using it incorrectly.  The [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) for `SimpleJdbcCall` could perhaps be more explicit, but it does say:

> A `SimpleJdbcCall` is a multi-threaded, reusable object representing a call to **a** stored procedure or a stored function.

In other words, each instance of `SimpleJdbcCall` is configured to invoke a specific stored procedure. Once configured, it shouldn't be changed.

If you need to invoke multiple stored procedures, you need to have multiple `SimpleJdbcCall` objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I must to create a new SimpleJdbcCall instance when I call different stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This concept does not seem to be very clear in the spring reference documentation as all the examples in there only have a single instance of SimpleJdbcCall which is used against one example procedure.

One SimpleJdbcCall instance per unique stored procedure is what is needed and the SimpleJdbcCall instances need to be initialized only once. They are thread safe once initialized.